# cms menu and pages links in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, content-management-system

i want to add a menu to in my cms in asp.net.
the functionality which i need is that, when user creates a new page so the page link should be added to the menu. The should be asked either to add the page link in the dropdown/nested menu or in the root menu.

any help please the cms is in c# asp.net.

with much thanks

Comment: i am creating my own cms

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to free CMS for ASP.NET: [ScottGu Blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/02/02/437220.aspx). Maybe that helps. I would suggest you learn ASP.NET first, before you try to write your own CMS.

Of course there are loads of other free .NET CMS systems, like Orchard, Umbraco, dotnetNuke etc.